# Edit Html.ActionLink output string

Tags: asp.net, html, actionlink

I'm trying to output the following HTML using Html.ActionLink:

```
<a href="/About" class="read-more">Read More<span class="arrow">→</span></a>
```

I'm getting it done by doing an ActionLink, which outputs an `<a>` tag and then manipulating the string.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("[[replace]]", "Index", "About", null, new { @class = "read-more" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[[replace]]", "Read More" + "<span class='arrow'>→</span>")%></p>
```

It'd be good if I could put HTML directly into the ActionLink but there doesn't seem to be a way based on my internet searches.  Sure, it works but it seems like a hack.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Aaron...Did you work this out?

I use Url.Action in the href attribute when I need something other than just the link text in the outputted HTML.

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("About") %>" class="read-more">Read More<span class="arrow">→</span></a>
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
-jc

Answer (score 1):

You could write you're own HTML helper class and make it fit whatever needs you have.  I've wrote a few before, I see the ones you get with MVC as just a start.

Here's a [link](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/vs2008/6358) with a tutorial. And [here's](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc-videos/video-402.aspx) and official MS video on how to.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the arrow and you could use an image, you could use stylesheet to put that image after the link

```
.readmore-link{background-image: url('/image.png'); padding-right: 16px; /*...*/}
```

just tweak the image position etc.

Otherwise I'd recommend writing extension method for HtmlHelper.